# NSMutableDictionary load problem with plist

Tags: objective-c

The following code, trying to fill in data.
But the data does not fill.

```
NSURL *request = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iphone.developer.tv.tr/PList/Kurlar.aspx?type=1"];

NSMutableDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:request];

NSLog(@"The count: %i", [plistDictionary count]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The file doesn't look like a valid NSDictionary representation for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kod</key>
    <string>USD</string>
    <key>Baslik</key>
    <string>Amerikan Doları</string>
    <key>Adet</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>DovizAlis</key>
    <real>1,5886</real>
    <key>DovizSatis</key>
    <real>1,5963</real>
    <key>EfektifAlis</key>
    <real>1,5875</real>
    <key>EfektifSatis</key>
    <real>1,5987</real>
</dict>
<dict>
...
</dict>
<dict>
...
</dict>
<dict>
...
</dict>
```

There is no "root" dictionary. The plist editor can open it but only shows the first dictionary. So I guess this is just an invalid file.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the text fields. not filling.
URL: http://iphone.developer.tv.tr/PList/Kurlar.aspx